# How can i use this action function to get the user information?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm actually working on a small react app, i have an action to check if the current user exist in on the firestore collection 'users' based on the uid, anad then get the user’s profile information.
It works actually this action, but i can't use it in my profile component to display it !

That's the action file:

```
import 'firebase/firestore'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

const getUser =()=>{ 
  return (dispatch)=>{
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
      if(firebaseUser){
        firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(firebaseUser.uid).get().then( doc => {
            const { displayName } = doc.data()
         //it works and it shows me on console the name i want
            console.log("display name in action: ",displayName)

            const currentUser = {
              uid: firebaseUser.uid,
              displayName
            }
            dispatch({
              type:'GET_USER',
              currentUser,
            })

        })
      }
    })
  }
}
export  default getUser ;
```

when i try to console log it in my profile file, it shows this error "**typeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.getUser().currentUser')**":

```
console.log("getting current user: ", this.props.getUser().currentUser )
```

I expect to display me the displayName but i got that error!

Comment: try just `console.log(this.props)`. maybe at first its not there, then it is there later

Comment: @azium actually that's right, at first it shows me undefined, then it display the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually looking for reducer. Action handler is not designed to return data to your component. Action idea is to store data to reducer.

Code below assumes that you have properly connected react-redux with your application.

src/actions/userAction.js

```
import 'firebase/firestore'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

export const getUser = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
            if (firebaseUser) {
                firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(firebaseUser.uid).get().then(doc => {
                    const {displayName} = doc.data();

                    const currentUser = {
                        uid: firebaseUser.uid,
                        displayName
                    };

                    dispatch({
                        type: 'GET_USER',
                        payload: currentUser
                    });
                })
            }
        })
    }
};
```

src/reducers/userReducer.js

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    data: {},
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_USER':
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

src/reducers/index.js

```
import userReducer from "./userReducer";

export default {
    user: userReducer
};
```

src/components/Example.js

```
import React from 'react';
import connect from "react-redux/es/connect/connect";
import {getUser} from "../actions/userAction";

class Example extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getUser();
    }

    render() {
        if (!Object.keys(this.props.user.data).length)
            return <div>Loading user's data</div>;

        return (
            <div>
                { JSON.stringify(this.props.user.data) }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        user: state.user
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    getUser,
})(Example);
```

Comment: thanks for replying, i'm properly connected react-redux with my application but that doesn't work, it shows at first the text **Loading user's data** then it display a blank page.

Comment: Aaaa now it's working, i just delete the condition to check for data in render.